# Is there a function to get adjacent edge id's, similar to neighbors()?

Tags: python, igraph

The neigbhors() function does most of what I want it to do, but I also need to check attributes on the adjoining edges. Is there a similar function for returning edge id's?

e.g

```
edge_ids = ig.neighbors_edges(vert, mode="OUT")
```

get_eid() would work with the pair of vertices, I assume in constant time, but this doesn't work for multiple edges between the same vertices.

Is there anything builtin that would be quick? Or is something like the following my best option:

```
edge_ids = [graph[source][target] for target in ig.neighbors(source, mode="OUT")]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  there is a such a function. It is `incident`. Here is a small example.

```
from igraph import * 

g1 = Graph()
g1.add_vertices(4)
g1.add_edges([(0,1),(1,2),(0,2),(2,3)])

g1.incident(1)
```